# Why the exclamation point in another StackOverflow posting involving telephone number REGEX?

Tags: regex

In [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation), the accepted answer has a number of comments.  One of the comments, by @jcmcbeth, suggests the following simple regular expression to use to obtain the digits of the telephone number submitted by a user:

```
string.replace("[^\d+!x]", "")
```

Immediately following the comment with this suggested regular expression, another questioner asks `why the !x part?`, which is then answered in the next comment: `The !x is there to keep any "x" character from getting stripped`.

This makes sense to me, except for the exclamation point `!`.  Looking at documentation for character classes in regular expressions, I do not see that the exclamation point is a special character, and it doesn't seem to me that the `x` requires a special character preceding it.  Also, from the discussion in the linked question, I do not see any comment indicating that an exclamation point might be part of a telephone number (which would explain its inclusion in the negated character class).

Can someone please explain to me why the exclamation point is present?  Thanks.

Comment: because regular expressions are exciting!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're absolutely right, the `x` is sufficient.  `!` just matches a literal `!`, inside a character class or out.  The only place it has any special meaning is when it's part of negative lookahead or a negative lookbehind.

Answer (score -3):

Surely  `[^\d+!x]`   means "NOT `'\'`, NOT `'d'`, NOT `'+'`, NOT `'!'` and NOT `'x'`".

`[ ]` is a character group.

`[^ ]` negates the list of characters.

Comment: Not quite. `\d` is the shorthand for digits; it works the same in a character class as it does anywhere else.  If you really wanted it to match a backslash or a `d` you would have to escape the backslash: `[^\\d+!x]`.  But that's not what the author intended.

Comment: Depends on the dialect. Before Perl, `[^\d]` would most certainly mean any character except backslash or d (or newline).